# How can I tell whether a package is installed via yum in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, package-management, yum

I am trying to write a script that installs packages, but if it fails at any point later in the script rolls back whatever it installed. Of course if the user has already previously installed a package I don't want to uninstall it out from under them. How can my script tell whether a package has been previously installed via yum?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I found the following on a semi-related [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447011/how-to-ensure-yum-install-was-successful-in-a-shell-script); the answer I needed didn't actually quite answer the question there (and was not selected as the correct answer) so I figured I'd post it here for others to find easier.

`yum list installed PACKAGE_NAME`

This command returns some human-readable output, but more importantly returns an exit status code; 0 indicates the package *is* installed, 1 indicates the package is *not* installed (does not check whether the package is valid, so `yum list installed herpderp-beepbopboop` will return a "1" just as `yum list installed traceroute` will if you don't have traceroute installed). You can subsequently check "$?" for this exit code.

Since the output is somewhat counter-intuitive, I used @Chris Downs' "condensed" version below in a wrapper function to make the output more "logical" (i.e. 1=installed 0=not installed):

```
function isinstalled {
  if yum list installed "$@" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    true
  else
    false
  fi
}
```

usage would be

`if isinstalled $package; then echo "installed"; else echo "not installed"; fi`

#### EDIT:

Replaced `return` statements with calls to `true` and `false` which help make the function more readable/intuitive, while returning the values bash expects (i.e. 0 for true, 1 for false).

If you're just checking for one package in your script, you may just be better off testing `yum list installed` directly, but (IMHO) the function makes it easier to understand what's going on, and its syntax is much easier to remember than `yum` with all the redirects to supress its output.

Comment: You don't need to manually check the value of `$?`, just wrap the command in a conditional: `if yum list installed "$package" >/dev/null 2>&1; then [...]`

Comment: I think your echo statements are reversed, no? `isInstalled` returns 1 if the package is installed; but 1 is evaluated to false in bash so "not installed" is echoed.

Comment: @FGreg good call... I've replaced the `return` statements with calls to `true` and `false`, so the function is easily readable yet returns the output bash expects.

Comment: OMG it's the 21st century, can't they have a proper option to tell if a package is installed so I don't have write functions or one liners!?

Answer (score 28):

Not exactly fulfilling the precondition of the question "via yum" but faster than "yum -q list" is:

```
rpm -q <package_name>
```

which returns the exact name of the possibly installed version as well as the error code "0" if installed and "1" if not.

Comment: Definitely faster, because `rpm` is local package manager. `yum` is for dealing with packages in remote repositories

Answer (score 10):

Simpler oneliner:

```
yum -q list installed packageX &>/dev/null && echo "Installed" || echo "Not installed"
```

Answer (score 0):

A handy script for yum:

`#!/bin/sh
pckarr=(wget mlocate bind-utils ANY_RANDOM_PACKAGE_NAME)
yum update -y
for i in  ${pckarr[*]}
 do
  isinstalled=$(rpm -q $i)
  if [ !  "$isinstalled" == "package $i is not installed" ];
   then
    echo Package  $i already installed
  else
    echo $i is not INSTALLED!!!!
    yum install $i -y
  fi
done
updatedb`

In pckarr array, list those packages which you want to install or check if that is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also read the return value `$?` from yum. Should be 0 if everything worked or positive depending on what kind of issues yum ran into. This is a good way if you want to take different actions if something fails.