# yum - check if package already installed

Tags: software-installation, yum

When I run `yum install <X>` where `<X>` has already been installed, `yum` exits with a return status of 1 and prints "Error: Nothing to do".

Aside from checking for this string in the output (which seems like a very shaky thing to base my script on), is there some way I can test whether the package already exists? Clearly, yum knows whether or not it already exists, since it's throwing that error, but how can I access that knowledge?

To add to this, some of the packages are downloaded by way of URLs, not package names, so checking `yum list installed` doesn't work.

Comment: `yum` knows by querying the rpm database. [for example](https://dpaste.de/Zbkk)

Comment: @Bratchley Is there a way to get that name from a package url?

Comment: You should be able to give `rpm` a full URL to the RPM you're interested in. [Example](https://dpaste.de/9feN) which will give you the package name. One note would be that it uses `wget` internally but seems to silently suppress errors.

Comment: @taliezin that's roughly equivalent to `rpm -qa packageName` except it's printed in a way that makes it look like `yum` output.

Comment: @Bratchley, sorry i saw the link later, but I deleted it.

Comment: Similar question is here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122681/how-can-i-tell-whether-a-package-is-installed-via-yum-in-a-bash-script

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your script use `rpm -q packagename`:

```
if  rpm -q  vim-enhanced
then
  echo "Already installed vim-enhanced"
else
  echo "Install vim-enhanced"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked well. I had to manually fiddle with the package name for packages which were obtained through urls, but other than that, it went smoothly.

Comment: I'm happy it worked. Sometimes package names can be tricky. I wish package names were slightly more normalized...

Answer (score 6):

You can try:

```
#yum list installed | grep tmux
tmux.x86_64                      1.9a-5.fc21        @updates
```

or:

```
#yum list installed tmux
Loaded plugins: langpacks
Installed Packages
tmux.x86_64                                                               1.9a-5.fc21                                                               @updates
```

Without `grep` you get some extra lines, but  both outputs can be piped through some text editor according to your needs.

Comment: the disadvantage   with this solution it hang if the list is huge somewho