# How to download packages without FTP access on a Linux Server if no download commands are listed?

Tags: command-line, fedora, software-installation, package-management, download

I am not a Linux expert and currently using a Fedora 23 Server (so only command line) with no FTP access for a project. I am used to install software directly in command line with prepared download commands, like - to state an example - the go-cd solution I currently use on my Fedora: https://docs.gocd.io/current/installation/install/server/linux.html

Now I have encountered a software that I want to install on my Fedora and I don't figure out how because the installation instruction does not state any download commands which suggests I have to download the package by clicking on a download button, unzip the package in some folder of my fedora server - a procedure that would only work if a.) I could paste the unzipped package through a FTP client, which does not work because I have no FTP access.

So is there a way to download any package only via command line? 
The software I want to download is this btw  http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3/installing.html

Comment: Did you check if it was available directly in a repository (to install with `yum`)?  What is stopping you from installing a FTP client since you care so much about FTP?

Comment: I believe `wget` or `curl` also have basic FTP download support.

Comment: @phk:  Keep up the faith as you are absolutely right.  But we still don't know why OP can't use FTP so that may not be a solution as they could either be absent or some ports may be blocked.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I thought about that but how/where to check if PMD is in yum (which is now actually dnf?)

Concerning FTP: I have a Fedora on a remote Server that I can reach only via PuTTY (SSH). The server is rented (not by me) and at least meanwhile I have no FTP access.

Comment: well you can download the software directly form curl or wget or if you can connect remotely through ssh you can simply use a utility called scp i hope it helps .

Comment: Thank you all for your time and contributions! It sees I solved it (see answer below). I still wonder though if it is possible to install packages in Fedora via command line that are neither in yum/dnf nor deployable via FTP (due to access restrictions e.g.).

Answer (score 0):

Seems I solved it, many thanks to all contributions in this thread! Sorry for posting an extra answer for this instead of a command but in a comment I cannot illustrate with pictures how I solved it. Furthermore I had to post one big picture containing 3 screens because SE prevents posting 3 pics with low reputation.

**Concerning the solution:**
Checking if the package was in yum (which is dnf now) was they key. (Step 1 in the pic) The command is: *dnf search packagename* (of course you have to replace the word packagename with your search key word.

Then I installed the package which I have marked and it was succesfull (Step 2 in the attached pic).

Afterwards I checked if the package is really installed (Step 3 in the pic, like it is described here ([yum - check if package already installed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192473/yum-check-if-package-already-installed))

[image]